# Alternative way to import json files to realtime database in firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was going through a google codelabs tutorial in which they show how to make a chat app https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0.

We have to select Database from the navigation menu in the firebase console & go into the overflow menu & select import project.

We have to browse to a folder and select a json file and then press on the import button.
The problem is that the Browse button is not working so:

Is there another way to import the JSON file into the realtime database?

[The pop up that comes up on clicking import project & in which the browse button desn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpnIc.png)

Comment: The Firebase database has an API that allows you to programmatically access it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/. A simple way would be to use `curl` and the REST API to upload the same content: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had similar issue on Chrome. The button works on Firefox

Answer (score 2):

The button works on Firefox, had some issue in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Vulcan by Firebase](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vulcan-by-firebase/oippbnlmebalopjbkemajgfbglcjhnbl) for any JSON updates in Firebase and it works perfect. Vulcan by Firebase is Chrome extension.

Comment: It seems Vulcan is not working any more. It cannot be found in Chrome Extensions too.